# How to create a Service to download XMPP contacts?

Tags: android, service, xmpp

In my app i am using XMPP for chatting, in this i have to create a service to download all the contacts from the XMPP sever to my DataBase. i am doing like below code now, it takes much time to get all contacts, i don't have interest user let to wait to complete download all contacts. 
Due to this reason i want to use a service to do this job in background and then store them in DB, i will use provider to update the contacts if database have a new contact.

I know how to create a service but here i am unable to pass parameter like Roster and XMPP connection to service, these parameters are required to download contacts from XMPP server.
please anybody guide me how to solve this problem.
this is the code i am using now.

```
public class GmailXmppClient { 

   public GmailXmppClient(ChatAccountsFragment _fragment, Context _context) {

      this.fragment = _fragment;
      this.context = _context;


      ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server_host, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
      m_connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
      try {
          m_connection.connect();
      } catch (XMPPException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public Roster getRoster() {
     Log.i(TAG, " getRoster ");
     return m_connection.getRoster();
  }

  public boolean Login(String uname, String pass ) throws XMPPException {

    m_connection.login(uname, pass);     
    this.fragment.Gtalk_logInComplete(uname, m_connection);             
    this.setPacketFilters();
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
    Log.i("ID", "" + presence);
    m_connection.sendPacket(presence);      
    return true;
  } 

  public void disconnect() {
     m_connection.disconnect();
  }
}
```

From the above code after this code

```
this.fragment.Gtalk_logInComplete(uname, m_connection);
```

this code will run to get contacts from xmpp server

```
private void getConts() {

   Roster roster = colors_xmpp_client.getRoster();
   String file_name;
   for (RosterEntry entry : roster.getEntries()) {
     if (entry.getType() == ItemType.to || entry.getType() == ItemType.both) {              

        boolean yes = Contact_data_source.checkUsername(entry.getUser());
        Log.i(TAG, "Con=" + yes);
        if (!yes) {
           String na = entry.getUser();
           String[] me = na.split("@");                     
           Bitmap buddy_img = buddyImage(entry, _connection);
           if (buddy_img != null)
               file_name = Store(buddy_img);
           else
               file_name = "";
           if (entry.getName() == null)
               Contact_data_source.createContact( entry.getUser(), entry.getUser(), Uname, file_name, UsedStrings.SipAccount, me[0] );
           else
               Contact_data_source.createContact( entry.getName(), entry.getUser(), Uname, file_name, UsedStrings.SipAccount, me[0] );
         } else {
          Log.i(TAG, "Con=exist");
         }
      }
    }               
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following flow:

1) start Activity, bind RosterService

2) register ContentObserver with desired context (application context, or activity)
    context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(uriRosterChanged, true, contentObserver);

3) send this context and contentObserver to RosterService

4) in service: get contact  and store it into db and !!! >>

5) in service: context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uriRosterChanged, contentObserver)

6) repeat i.4 for the next contact


i.5 -> will fire contentObserver.onChange method, so here you may refresh your contacts list

How 2 send parameters to service **2 ways** described with extras and direct method call (*setRosterNConnection()*):

**Activity** code:

```
...
RosterService mService;
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RosterService.class);
    intent.putExtra("Key", "Value");
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    ...
}
...
Roster mRoster ;
XMPPConnection mConnection;
...
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();       
        mService.setRosterNConnection(mRoster, mConnection);
        mService.doJob();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                mService = null;
    }
};
...
```

**RosterService** code:

```
// some class LocalBinder extends Binder{...} if some needs
private  LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); // class LocalBinder extends Binder{...}
...
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
    if(extras == null)
        Log.d("RosterService","extras is empty");
    else
    {
        Log.d("RosterService","extras not empty");
        String key = (String) extras.get("Key");
        ...
    }
    return mBinder;
}
...
public void setRosterNConnection (Roster roster , XMPPConnection connection){
...
}
...
public void doJob(){
 // get and save contacts
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it in a AsyncTask.

AsyncTask just will do the work on another thread, just if user close your activity the asyncTask will be stopped.

Comment: I did it by using asynctask, if user use this he have to wait to complete the download process till the end. i don't want to let him to wait like that.

Comment: If your code runs inside the AsyncTask then your user can use all your app without the contacts download blocks the UI.

Using a service the user will have to wait also to the end of service to get the contacts. Maybe I'm missing something but I don't get the point of using the service.

Comment: Downloading Contacts code running in AsyncTask only, when it runs if user chooses another activity after some time my app getting force close.